# Video streaming between iPhones

Tags: ios, video, streaming, opentok, tokbox

How can I stream live video between two iPhones in my app? I used openTok (tokbox.com), but there I can't processing video, for example find face or something like that. Is there way to connect two devices via server? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find, great solution is quickblox.com

Answer (score 0):

Using OpenTok for iOS, there currently is no way to inspect the video frames individually. This might be a feature in the future.

Comment: are you saying that the snapshots are low resolution? badly compressed? or some other kind of issue?